# How to create a bot on DialogFlow using their REST API?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is there any way to create Dialogflow agents via the RESTful API?

In the documentation, you only have the getAgent method. I would like to know if there is any strategy plan for creating agents through the REST API?

Doc
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects

Comment: Please upvote and mark my answer as correct if you found my answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to create a Dialogflow agent via the API at this time.

Comment: May I know why it is this way? It very limiting.

Comment: What is your use case for creating Dialogflow agents via the API?  I should also note you can only create one Dialogflow agent per Google Cloud project.

Comment: I have created a detailed question on my requirement here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52465832/dialogflow-vs-lex-for-streaming-intent-detection. In essence, I have web application which will enable user to create agent dynamically by abstracting away lot of the heavy lifting. For this purpose, I need to create new agents via API on demand. I am aware that DialogFlow provides agent versioning (beta) but the real use case is not as I intend to use it. Also because since each GCP can only have one agent, dynamically directing my intent detecting request to multiple agents is a bit tricky.